# Adding an Image programmatically between an UIImage and UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an `UIImage` above which I am supposed to add another `UIImage` programmatically, above which there will be an `UILabel`. I successfully added the Image but it overlaps the Label.

If 1. BG image 2.Image to be added programmatically    3. Label,

then the sequence I want is,
1
2
3

and what I get is

1
3
2

2 overlaps my Label. I have tried Send to Back, Bring to Front and `bringSubviewToFront`. It did not work.

Comment: How're you adding your views ??? Show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is add the particular images in that sequence itself, i.e. in the ViewWillAppear or the ViewDidLoad method use the method 
`self.view addSubview:BGimage` .
Then add the next image on the previous one like
 `BGimage addSubview:image2` . 
Similarly add the UILabel on the Image 2 like 
`Image2 addSubview:Label`

This will put your images and the label in the particular sequence you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *img2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"TDK 3 Speaker.png"]];
//img2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[BgImage addSubview:img2];
UILabel *lblText=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 200, 40)];
lblText.text=@"I am Here";
//lblText.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[BgImage addSubview:lblText];
```

Comment: try adding label as subview to 2(second image) and add label(3) as subview to 1(background image)

Answer (score 0):

try this, add QuartzCore.framework and in your header file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and in you implementation file

```
your_Label.layer.zPosition=your_secondImage.layer.zPosition+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of adding is important here the later one comes in front
Add subview should  be called in an order first BGImage then Image and then  Label

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show BG Image (1) then you can also use `UIView` instead of `UIImageView` You can also do the samething with `UIImageView` as well.

```
[yourUIView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBackGroundImage"]]];

[yourUIView setFrame:CGRect(x,y,width,height)]; //yourExpectedFrame;
```

Now, create a `UIImageView` (2) with `UIImage` and also set a `frame` within that `UIView`, also create a `UILabel` (3) and give it `frame` as per the `UIView` and accordingly with `UIImageView`. That's all. You done!.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure,but you try this:

Set the property masksToBounds: YES for the UIImageView.